# Is it possible to create a common cross platform UI using html5 camera/image picker

Tags: html, filepicker

I'm creating a web app that asks users to upload photos using html5 `<input type="file" accept="image/*" />`

Is it possible to create a common UI for selecting the camera or cameral roll accross android and ios devices?

This is how the native UI pickers look:

[image]

[image]

I would like to make them both look different with a custom UI.